# Python is ignoring my if

Tags: python

Could anybody tell me why this loop ignores the if? (edit: this is the whole code - the function which gives back a number.)

```
time_now = time()
number = np.loadtxt("11.txt", unpack=True, dtype='int64')
lenx = len(number[0,:])
leny = len(number[:,0])
lennum = 4
#prods = np.zeros(lenx*leny*4).reshape(lenx,leny,4)
maxnum = 0

for m in range(0,leny):
    for n in range(0,lenx):
        prods = lookaround(n,m)

        if prods > maxnum:
            maxnum = prods

time_end = time();

elapsed = time_end - time_now

print(prods, elapsed)
```

Comment: There is not enough information here

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are looking for a maximal value, you probably want to use [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max).

Comment: Why don't you just use `max(lookaround(n, m) for m in range(leny) for n in range(lenx))`?

Comment: @Blender It might be worth explaining what a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) is to go with that.

Comment: I'm iterating trough a function which gives me back a number. I just want to check if it is higher than anything before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because `prods` is always less than or equal to `maxnum`? what value did you use to initialize `maxnum`? it should be set at a very small number before the loops, say `maxnum = float("-inf")`. Another possibility is that `lookaround` is returning an incorrect value, unit-test that function.

Comment: I did, output gives a lot of positive numbers. Nothing below 0

Comment: You're not actually _using_ `maxnum` after the loops. Maybe the last line should be this? `print(maxnum, elapsed)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just write it like this:

```
from itertools import product

time_now = time()

number = np.loadtxt("11.txt", unpack=True, dtype='int64')
lenx = len(number[0,:])
leny = len(number[:,0])

maxnum = max(lookaround(n, m) for n, m in product(range(lenx), range(leny)))

time_end = time();    
elapsed = time_end - time_now

print(maxnum, elapsed)   # <== maxnum not prods
```